# Receiving Memory warning and crash after capturing photo UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I've written a tiny single view app for Ios5-6 that allows the user to capture a photo image and then sets said image to a image view. The ImagePicker View is opening just fine but when I click capture the app closes and I receive the following console output. (The app works as expected when running in ios simulator 6. malfunctions on iphone4s device)

2013-01-25 15:21:11.129 LearningPhotos[10914:707] Could not find mapped image Silver_ISXSilent.png
2013-01-25 15:21:11.250 LearningPhotos[10914:707] Could not find mapped image ColorOnGrayShadow_ISXSilent.png
2013-01-25 15:21:16.678 LearningPhotos[10914:707] Received memory warning.

ViewController Interface:

```
    //
//  ViewController.h
//  LearningPhotos
//
//  Created by Jared Rainey on 1/24/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Volatile App Group. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    UIImage *image;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *imageLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)imageButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController Implementation:

```
    //
//  ViewController.m
//  LearningPhotos
//
//  Created by Jared Rainey on 1/24/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Volatile App Group. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@implementation ViewController


@synthesize imageView,imageLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    //If Camera source type available use it otherwise photo library
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }else{
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    }

    //allow no image editing
    [imagePicker setAllowsEditing:NO];

    //set imagepickercontroller delegate to self
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];     
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)imageButton:(id)sender {
    //Image Button has been pressed
    //load image picker view dependent on UIImagePickerController source type
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    image = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}

-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Device logs:

```
Incident Identifier: 6084670F-7944-4D19-8953-A9582801A161
CrashReporter Key:   e3fd67afdfbdcc8a506fa6b75e4c965b76c10346
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Sun Apr  8 21:51:47 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1878.11.10~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8940X
Date:                2013-01-25 16:42:36 -0500
Time since snapshot: 43 ms

Free pages:        812
Active pages:      3403
Inactive pages:    1987
Throttled pages:   97220
Purgeable pages:   127
Wired pages:       25283
Largest process:   SpringBoard

Processes
         Name                 UUID                    Count resident pages
  LearningPhotos <4965639c91ae38ae9d40911923ef0502>   10251 (jettisoned) (active)
     debugserver <2408bf4540f63c55b656243d522df7b2>     163
        installd <0f9e14173c503a8089f7f8cd0329a1a0>     548
      MobileMail <eed7992f4c1d3050a7fb5d04f1534030>    1386 (jettisoned)
     MobilePhone <8f3f3e982d9235acbff1e33881b0eb13>    1123 (jettisoned)
            ptpd <62bc5573db7a352ab68409e87dc9abb9>     494
springboardservi <b74f5f58317031e9aef7e95744c816ca>     307
notification_pro <373a488638c436b48ef0801b212593c4>     106
notification_pro <373a488638c436b48ef0801b212593c4>     110
             atc <1e5f2a595709376b97f7f0fa29368ef1>     652
notification_pro <373a488638c436b48ef0801b212593c4>      95
notification_pro <373a488638c436b48ef0801b212593c4>     102
    syslog_relay <b07876a121a432d39d89daf531e8f2bd>      74
            afcd <c3cc9d594b523fd1902fb69add11c25d>     126
     dataaccessd <473ff40f3bfd3f71b5e3b4335b2011ee>     903
    mediaserverd <f03b746f09293fd39a6079c135e7ed00>    1146
      aosnotifyd <8cf4ef51f0c635dc920be1d4ad81b322>     419
            iapd <0a747292a113307abb17216274976be5>     564
   absinthed.N94 <2e1b2b6827f73747a686445a7a4d2db9>     115
        SCHelper <9b0b21c547c23b8a876271fee80f037a>     139
        networkd <80ba40030462385085b5b7e47601d48d>     165
            flux <204b55baaf0b372789e1a4da2b1c73e3>     389
        BTServer <31e82dfa7ccd364fb8fcc650f6194790>     576
      aggregated <a12fa71e6997362c83e0c23d8b4eb5b7>     413
            apsd <e7a29f2034083510b5439c0fb5de7ef1>     312
   fairplayd.N94 <e69a54203b7b3293ad3b0f8d83fa3ce1>     161
       fseventsd <914b28fa8f8a362fabcc47294380c81c>     179
         imagent <9c3a4f75d1303349a53fc6555ea25cd7>     866
   mDNSResponder <86ccd4633a6c3c7caf44f51ce4aca96d>     237
    mediaremoted <327f00bfc10b3820b4a74b9666b0c758>     290
           wifid <3001cd0a61fe357d95f170247e5458f5>     365
     sbsettingsd <e9a2c6b3c8a722b2bae7541bb247b81d>     334
    springflashd <3927dd5f9d5d3e3785a411a3283b4253>     374
       locationd <cf31b0cddd2d3791a2bfcd6033c99045>    1194
       ISXDaemon <54a1918090fb3c81acbd60b283de91a5>     263
          powerd <133b7397f5603cf8bef209d4172d6c39>     173
       lockdownd <b06de06b9f6939d3afc607b968841ab9>     268
      CommCenter <2c0aa3aba43a394d86f294959dbc61bd>     966
     SpringBoard <c74dc89dec1c3392b3f7ac891869644a>   42475 (active)
         configd <ee72b01d85c33a24b3548fa40fbe519c>     658
         syslogd <7153b590e0353520a19b74a14654eaaa>     229
         notifyd <f6a9aa19d33c3962aad3a77571017958>     275
  UserEventAgent <dc32e6824fd33bf189b266102751314f>     402
         launchd <5fec01c378a030a8bd23062689abb07f>     175

**End**
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am new to ios development and I am looking forward to figuring out the issue as I have been trying everything I could find here in the forum.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

here's my guess:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    imageView.image = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}
```

your image var may not be retaining the image you get from the info.  It may be crashing because you are setting the imageview's image after dismissing the picker view controller.

Comment: Thank you for your response I have switched the dismissal to after I set image view to the received image as suggested. I am receiving the same outcome of the app crashing. I would like to also mention that it crashes prior to reaching the typical use or retake view. (same console output as well.

Comment: Interestingly enough when using the front lower resolution camera the app does not crash...

Comment: can you post som more info? The log that you see after the crash would be helpful. Add an exception breakpoint, to see at what line it is crashing.

Comment: The device logs are added. Please let me know if there is anything else that could help along the way. I'm trying to use the analyzer now. I wonder if the backfacing camera is just taking to high a resolution of a picture to store in the iUIImageView...

Comment: try adding @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image; in your .h file? The log you posted is not helpful.

Comment: I apologize. What log are you asking for?

Answer (score 0):

You probably getting crash because of memory warning. Try not to save each image as it may weight 2-3 Mb for back high-resolution camera, or do recycling of memory somehow.